# How to use a static List<T> as a cache object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, collections, synchronization

I have a static `List<T>` as a cache object that is being heavily read by multiple treads. I Need to refresh the object every 5 minutes from the database.

The problem is that if I update the object while it being used by one of the threads, the `foreach` loop will throw an exception.

I have tried to implement flags like `inUse = true` and `inUpdate = true`, together with a *while* loops that wait for the flags to get set or released, but eventually it became too cumbersome and I think that there is a bug that prevents the object from being updated at all.

Is there something like a design pattern for such a case that I can use?

---

**Edit:**

Based on [Jim Mischel's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558341/how-to-use-a-static-listt-as-a-cache-object/15558578#15558578), I was able to produce the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static Timer g;
        static Timer f;
        static Timer r;
        static Timer l;

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            f=new Timer(
                o => SetK(new Random().Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)), 
                null, 0, 1);

            l=new Timer(
                o => SetK(new Random().Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)), 
                null, 1, 1);

            g=new Timer(o => RunLoop(), null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
            r=new Timer(o => RunLoop(), null, 1001, Timeout.Infinite);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void SetK(int g) 
        {
            try {
                if(g<0) {
                    List<int> k=new List<int>(10);

                    k.Insert(0, g);
                    k.Insert(1, g);
                    k.Insert(2, g);
                    k.Insert(3, g);
                    k.Insert(4, g);
                    k.Insert(5, g);
                    k.Insert(6, g);
                    k.Insert(7, g);
                    k.Insert(8, g);
                    k.Insert(9, g);

                    SynchronizedCache<Int32>.Set(k);
                }
                else {
                    List<int> k=new List<int>(5);
                    k.Insert(0, g);
                    k.Insert(1, g);
                    k.Insert(2, g);
                    k.Insert(3, g);
                    k.Insert(4, g);

                    SynchronizedCache<Int32>.Set(k);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public static void RunLoop() 
        {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        SynchronizedCache<Int32>.GetLock().EnterReadLock();

                        foreach(var g in SynchronizedCache<Int32>.Get()) {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine(g);
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        SynchronizedCache<Int32>.GetLock().ExitReadLock();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SynchronizedCache<T> 
    {
        private static ReaderWriterLockSlim 
            cacheLock=new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        private static List<T> cache=new List<T>();

        public static ReaderWriterLockSlim GetLock() 
        {
            return cacheLock;
        }

        public static void Set(List<T> list) 
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();

            try {
                cache=list;
            }
            finally {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public static List<T> Get() 
        {
            return cache;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have multiple threads each doing "foreach" on your List<T>?

Comment: @Matt Yes. The threads constantly iterate the static List<T> using the foreach loop.

Comment: Well of course that's going to cause a problem, the way you're using it. You're not updating the list. You're creating a whole new one! The idea is that you create the list once, and then you enumerate and update that one list. If you want to swap out the list, then you need to synchronize access to `k` itself, rather than to the internal backing store.

Comment: @JimMischel I find is somewhat weird to update the list. I think it will cause even more trouble than replacing it with a new one. What if the collection size changes, does List<T> support increasing/reducing its size? Maybe you can show a code example how exactly you suggest updating the list. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: `List<T>` will dynamically change size. That's the whole point of using it rather than an array. It occurs to me that your code could be failing if your `Insert` method doesn't obtain the write lock. Any method that modifies the list has to enter the write lock. Methods that just read can enter the read lock. You might ask @Servy for an example of his technique for updating the list, as it might be more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there isn't a `System.Collections.Concurrent` collection that maps well to a `List<T>`. In cases where I need such a thing, I use a wrapper that internally uses a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to protect it. For example:

```
public class ConcurrentList<T>: IList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _theList;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwlock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public ConcurrentList()
    {
        _theList = new List<T>();
    }

    public ConcurrentList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _theList = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public ConcurrentList(int size)
    {
        _theList = new List<T>(size);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        _rwlock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _theList.IndexOf(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _rwlock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _rwlock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _theList.Insert(index, item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _rwlock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            _rwlock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _theList[index];
            }
            finally
            {
                _rwlock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _rwlock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _theList[index] = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                _rwlock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        _rwlock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in _theList)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _rwlock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    // other methods not implemented, for brevity
}
```

}

It's a little work setting it up the first time, but after that it works well. It supports any number of concurrent readers, or just one writer.

Any number of readers can be accessing the list concurrently. If a thread wants to write to the list, it has to obtain the write lock. In order to obtain the write lock, it waits until all readers are done. No threads can enter the read lock once a thread has requested the write lock. Readers will be allowed through once the writer has finished.

@Servy has a good suggestion, too. If your threads are just reading, and periodically you refresh the list (i.e. completely build a new one) from the database, then it's very easy to do as he says.

Comment: Nice! EnterReadLock() doesn't block does it?

Comment: @Matt Yes, it does, if someone else has the lock.

Comment: @Jim this still won't help.  If someone else is foreaching over the list and an item is added the iterator will throw a concurrent modification exception.  You could get rid of the exception by using a `for` instead of a `foreach`, but if another thread can be adding/removing items out from under you during iteration, you're still going to be in a world of hurt.

Comment: @Jim ya that was my worry. I like the implementation, but doesn't quite solve the problem for all the threads doing their foreach loops.

Comment: @Servy: If somebody is foreaching over the list, one would assume that the he had entered the read lock, which means that nobody can enter the write lock, meaning that it can't be modified.

Comment: @Matt: It absolutely does solve the problem. `EnterReadLock` will block if another thread has the write lock. But it will allow any number of readers through. Similarly, `EnterWriteLock` allows *one* writer, and blocks all other readers and writers. Let me update my answer to be more complete.

Comment: @Jim ahh that makes more sense, would totally solve the problem then!

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for the answer, but it sometimes fails, see OP edit.

Comment: @JimMischel Based on your example I was able to produce an alteration that suits my needs. Take a look at the OP edit:

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the concurrent collections from the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

> The `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace provides several thread-safe collection classes that should be used in place of the corresponding types in the `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces whenever multiple threads are accessing the collection concurrently.

Comment: I've always found that it is difficult to match a list from the Concurrent namespace - there is ConcurrentBag, but depending how you use the list, it isn't a very god replacement, IMHO - A readerwriterlock may be a useful construct as well.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than mutating a single list, in this case it's most likely better to create a new list that incorporates the changes that you want (i.e. has additional items, doesn't add some items, etc.) and then just set the cache value to refer to the new list.  Since setting the value of the cache is atomic you ensure that once someone gets the value out of the cache it might be a tiny bit stale, but they'll still be able to read it just fine.

Comment: Yes, I am  thinking about this solution, but I worry that doing a copy by value each time the object is being accessed, will create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and probably the one I'd go with if my threads are strictly readers (except for the periodic update, of course). You should add an example.

Comment: @user1615362 It doesn't need to be copied when read, only when mutated.  It would work well if the list is not particularly large, and if it's read much more often than it's changed.  The overhead isn't "unnecessary" either, it's serving a valuable purpose.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, but I am having trouble understanding exactly what you mean. Can you please provide a code example so that it can be more clear?

Comment: @user1615362 You take the item out of the cache, you make a copy (which can be done through a single call to the List's constructor), then change that copy, and set the cache value to be the copy when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to use the mutex design pattern to avoid race conditions. Fortunately, the .NET framework has a standard implementation of the mutex design pattern; you can read the documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx .

Comment: But a mutex would only allow a single reader at a time. A reader/writer lock would be better in this situation.

Comment: You can convert the collection to a property and put the mutex only in the setter. I never tried this, but I think that this solution could work.

Comment: But if you put the mutex only in the setter, that only prevents multiple concurrent writers. It doesn't prevent you from writing when somebody else is reading.